# Why does Firefox look slow? (Intel UHD 750)

Tags: firefox, performance

I'm leaving Windows behind and want to use Linux from now on. My new PC with Intel i5-11500 has still the stock cooler in it, and I'll replace it with a more silent cooler later.

I'm using Ubuntu 21.04.

- Board: ASUS PRO H510M-C/CSM.
- CPU: i5-11500 @ 2.70GHz × 12.
- RAM: 16 GB, Ballistix DDR4-3600.

So, compared to Windows, it's currently a loud PC in Linux. The fan speeds up often, I'm planning to get fancontrol working. The UEFI fan settings are as good as I could get them, unfortunately the fan control options in this ASUS mainboard don't let me set RPM values for temperatures or anything like that, only the minimum RPM and how long it should take to speed up the fan, up to 25 seconds. My old mainboard was much better in this regard.

My actual question is, why does it look so wrong when I run `htop`? It displays 12 threads all at around 30-40% CPU when only Firefox is open playing an mp3, and around 60-70% CPU on all 12 threads when Youtube is playing a video that's already buffered. It's a 144p video with just one image and music in it.

It can't use that much CPU for decoding mp3 or aac, can it? Is there something wrong in my setup?

Comment: Graphics: llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.1, 256 bits). A bigger Firefox window gives higher CPU usage in the Youtube case, even 12 x 80%.

Comment: Appearently there was no hardware-accelerated driver installed. Installing Ubuntu 20.04 and doing `sudo apt install linux-oem-20.04b` fixed this, CPU usage now is 12 x ~8% at video playback in Youtube. The About screen says Graphics is now Mesa Intel® Graphics (RKL GT1), although at 4k via Displayport it is only 30 Hz, which I see, and `xrandr` says so. And unfortunately now the other problem is back, video playback often gets stuck as described here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1335404/video-playback-problems-intel-uhd-750

Comment: Using HDMI gives me 60 Hz at 4k, although videos still get stuck.